# UILabel/UITextField doesn't update with asynchronous HTTP request

Tags: ios, swift, http, request

When I make an asynchronous http request, my `UITextField` containing the text doesn't update, it only shows the text when I click on it (also with the `UILabel`), I tried putting it before the `viewDidLoad()` override method but I got nothing

The HTTP request:

```
func asincrono(){
    print("A buscar: \(completeLink!) \n")
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?jscmd=data&format=json&bibkeys=ISBN:\(completeLink!)")!
    let urlSession:NSURLSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let bloque = { (datos : NSData?, resp: NSURLResponse?,error:NSError?)-> Void in let texto = NSString(data: datos!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        if error?.code>=400 && error?.code<500 {
            self.jsonText.text = "Error, bad connection"
        }else if error?.code == nil{
            /*let index1 = (texto! as String).startIndex.advancedBy(2)
            let substring1 = (texto! as String).substringToIndex(index1)
            print(substring1)*/
            self.jsonText.text = texto! as String
            print("Datos obtenidos: \n\n\(self.jsonText.text!)")
        }
        print(texto!)
    }
    let dt = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: bloque)
    dt.resume()
}
```

The `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    asincrono()
    super.viewDidLoad()
    jsonText.text = jsonText.text
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you retrieve the value from the http request and update the text field?

Comment: What's the point of the line `jsonText.text = jsonText.text` in your `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @rmaddy It was a try for updating my `UITextField`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI related changes should be done on main thread, so as you described above these types errors may happen if you modify UI related items in async methods. So you should include the UILabel modifying line in a sync method.
Update UILabel like

```
   func asincrono(){
        print("A buscar: \(completeLink!) \n")
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?jscmd=data&format=json&bibkeys=ISBN:\(completeLink!)")!
        let urlSession:NSURLSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let bloque = { (datos : NSData?, resp: NSURLResponse?,error:NSError?)-> Void in let texto = NSString(data: datos!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            if error?.code>=400 && error?.code<500 {
               dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.jsonText.text = "Error, bad connection"
                 })
            } else if error?.code == nil{
                /*let index1 = (texto! as String).startIndex.advancedBy(2)
                let substring1 = (texto! as String).substringToIndex(index1)
                print(substring1)*/
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.jsonText.text = texto! as String
                 })
                print("Datos obtenidos: \n\n\(self.jsonText.text!)")
            }
            print(texto!)
        }
        let dt = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: bloque)
        dt.resume()
    }
```

By the way here is the viewDidLoad()

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        asincrono()
    }
```

You don't need to add

> jsonText.text = jsonText.text

in viewDidLoad()

Comment: This may be the problem, but in the absence of code from the OP is really just a guess.  I would suggest you post a comment seeking more information before posting an answer

Comment: Thank you Paulw ..

Answer (score 1):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

        lbl?.text = "Hello"

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

NSString myNewString=@"This is updated string";
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

          myLabel.text=myNewString

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will be helpful for you

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
          self.label.text= @"Updated String"
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake with viewDidLoad is **super.viewDidLoad()** method first then include the other methods, its change then code below format,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        asincrono()

        jsonText.text = jsonText.text

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }
```

hope its helpful

Comment: This change will not fix the problem at all. There's nothing wrong with calling other code before `super.viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: its problem occur this form my code, so its my thought

Comment: See the other 4 answers for the actual reason for the problem.

Comment: ok i will check it